# How to open a second bootstrap3 modal window only after passing validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have two modal windows, the first window has the form with validator (http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator), and the second with the text like "Thanks for posting." I wrote this code for my input button:

```
<input data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thanks" type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-md button-space">
```

But when I click on this button the first window is closed without checking the validation. How can I fixed that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need second modal to show the message only.
After validation you can replace html of modal body class using javascript function to show message.

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if !(e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
   $(".modal-body").html("Thanks for posting.");
   setTimeout(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal("hide");
    }, 200);
  }
});
```

Comment: But how can I do this after validation?

Comment: You should paste here complete model html instead of only button or update your question. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer. Hopefully it will work for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is not much code to go on for exact answer to resolve the problem so;

when I click on this button the first window is closed without checking the validation

```
 <input data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thanks" type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-md button-space">
```

It could be of 2 reasons,

- Validation plugin is not bind correctly with form
- `data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thanks"` in the above button close the modal and not letting the validation plugin doing it's job

And your 2nd question, How to open a second bootstrap3 modal window only after passing validation

- First remove the `data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thanks"` cause it's closing the form modal and fix the validation issue by checking the form is correctly bind with validation plugin.
- Second bind the above button in validation plugin with if success condition so if validation success then is shows ThankYou note in 2nd modal.

SideNote: this all effort is useless if you are not posting form via Ajax because without Ajax after validation form submit and refresh the page and Thankyou modal will show but only for couple of seconds

Following is an example code;

Modal With From

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Form</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="myform2" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="#">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label popup-label">Full Name</label>
                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary" id="Validate">Validate</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Form Validation

```
$('#myform2').bootstrapValidator({
    excluded: ':disabled',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            fullname: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Full Name field is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        max: 15,
                        message: 'The Full Name must be more than 5 and less than 15 characters long'
                    },
                }
            }
        },
      submitButtons: '#Validate'
    }).on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
            $("#ThanksModal").modal('show'); //show popup with thankyou note
});
```

If you check above, the submit button has id `Validate` in form and bind in validation plugin `submitButtons: '#Validate'` with success condition `'success.form.bv'` and `ThanksModal` only show if validation successful.

Modal With Thankyou Note after Validation

```
<div id="ThanksModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Form</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Thank You Comes Here After Validation</h4> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this Helps

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/my2kj5pr/2/)